# js iterate json get every single character from json

Tags: javascript, json

I have this a json that i want iterate and get the value from it and set and some variables but i'm facing some problems reading it

Here is my json:

```
{"bit":[{"id":81,"value":"aaaa"},{"id":83,"value":"bbbb"}]}
```

And everytime i try to iterate i get undefined or i get every single character from the json and this is not what i pretend:

Here is what i already tried:

**1)**

```
   JSON.stringify(objArray);
    for (var key in objArray) {
      if (objArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + objArray[key]);
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
0 -> {
1 -> "
2 -> b
3 -> i
4 -> t
5 -> "
 ...
```

**2)**

```
JSON.parse(objArray);
for (var key in objArray) {
  if (objArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + objArray[key]);
  }
}
```

Same output as before

**3**

```
for (var key in objArray) {
      if (objArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + objArray[key]);
      }
    }
```

Same output

i already tried other iterators i saw on another post:

And i what to iterate and get 81,aaa ; 83,bbb

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your second example try `objArray = JSON.parse(objArray);` as `JSON.parse()` will return the parsed value, although this will only return you `"bit -> [object Object], [object Object]"`

Comment: i get [object Object],[object Object] when i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to return the value from `JSON.parse` and then you have to iterate the `bit` array of `objArray`, as right now you're only looking at the keys on the top level.

```js
var objArray = '{"bit":[{"id":81,"value":"aaaa"},{"id":83,"value":"bbbb"}]}'
objArray = JSON.parse(objArray);

for (var bit in objArray.bit) {
  for (var key in objArray.bit[bit]) {
    if (objArray.bit[bit].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + objArray.bit[bit][key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `objArray` is a string, `JSON.parse` will parse the json as a string :

```
    var output = Object.values(JSON.parse(objArray)["bit"]).map(elt => {
       return elt.id + '->' + elt.value;
    }).join(';');

    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> And everytime i try to iterate i get undefined or i get every single character from the json and this is not what i pretend

**Reason :** You are trying to parse **`JSON String`** instead of **`JSON Object`**

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonStr = '{"bit":[{"id":81,"value":"aaaa"},{"id":83,"value":"bbbb"}]}';

for (var key in jsonStr) {
  if (jsonStr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + jsonStr[key]);
  }
}
```

**Correct solution :**

First convert `JSON String` into `JSON Object` with the help of `JSON.parse()` method then parse it.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonStr = '{"bit":[{"id":81,"value":"aaaa"},{"id":83,"value":"bbbb"}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for (var key in jsonObj) {
      if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " , jsonObj[key]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.parse()` takes json string as argument and returns a JSON object. 
This should work if json string is proper.

```
var key = JSON.parse(objArray);
for (key in objArray) {
  if (objArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + objArray[key]);
  }
}
```